# Another Riley that rhymes, what am I this time?

Tags: riddle

> At my end, you'll want a slice.
>   My center hides a paradise.
>   Seek qualification within my head.
>   I am something from which people were fed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> a **[credenza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credenza)**.

> At my end, you'll want a slice.

> **Za** is short for *pizza*, which is cut into slices.

> My center hides a paradise.

> **Eden** is a biblical garden paradise

> Seek qualification within my head.

> **Cred** is short for *credibility*.

> I am something from which people were fed.

> A **credenza** is a dining room cupboard originating centuries ago in Italy.

Comment: If the suffix is really rot13(mn), shouldn't it be something like "the end of my end"?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel It is actually a [common abbreviation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/za#Noun).

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know that. Fair enough then :)

Comment: Well done, @noedne.